# Program does not get text or set text

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# windows form project my program is not able to get the text from a text box, nor set the text box. I am able to register button clicks, so it seems that the programs GUI thread is okay.

```
private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am being pressed");
    textBox2.Text = "Test";
    this.Refresh();
}
```

As you can see from the code when the button is pressed the output panel says "I am being pressed". However, the text box does not visually update and say "Test".

Is there a reason why I am not able to set or get text. I have tried appending the text, but that is not my intention.

My guess is that the form is not focused perhaps, since I have changed what form is showing. The code below is from the first form class. `lobby` is a new `Form` that I show.

```
if (correct)
{
    lobby lob = new lobby(client, this);
    this.Hide(); // this is the first form the user sees, I have hidden it. If I close this form then the application exits.
    lob.Show(); // this is the form that I show after the user logs in with right credentials. Textbox.text = "test" does not work on this for some reason.                
}
```

In the first form window I am able to use the `Text` method and retrieve/set values.

But I cannot do the same in the second form.

--------Edit-------
This is the GUI builder for the second form.
[image: GUI Buider]
You can see the name field is called "TextBox2".

lobby.cs file

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClientMMO
{
    public partial class lobby : Form
    {
        static int counter;
        private Socket client;
        private Form1 form1;

        public lobby()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public lobby(Socket client)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.client = client;   

        }

        public lobby(Socket client, Form1 form1) : this(client)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.form1 = form1;

            textBox2.Text = "Test";

        }

    }
}
```

lobby.Designer.cs

```
namespace ClientMMO
{
    partial class lobby
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(107, 90);
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(251, 20);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // lobby
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(511, 413);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
            this.Name = "lobby";
            this.Text = "lobby";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
    }
}
```

This is the first form that the user sees. Everything works normal here, as it should.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ClientMMO
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        User test;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ConnectToServer();
        }

        private void ConnectToServer()
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1234);
            client.Connect(ep);
            Console.WriteLine("connnected");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test = new User();
            test.UserName = textBox1.Text;
            test.Password = textBox2.Text;
            client.Send(ClassToByteArray(test));
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            client.Receive(data);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            label1.Text = returndata;
            //Console.WriteLine(returndata);
            string b = "Logged in";

            int result = 0;
            string str1 = "Logged in";


            result = string.Compare(str1, returndata);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                button1.Visible = false;
                byte[] shit = new byte[1024];
                client.Receive(shit);
                Console.WriteLine(shit.ToString());
                string sfs = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(shit);
                label1.Text = String.Empty;
                label1.Text = sfs;

                int port = Int32.Parse(sfs);
                client.Close();
                client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPAddress ipAddresse = IPAddress.Loopback;
                IPEndPoint epe = new IPEndPoint(ipAddresse, port);
                client.Connect(epe);
                Console.WriteLine("connected to another server");


                /*------------------------------------This is where I open up my new window --------------------*/


                lobby lob = new lobby(client, this);
                this.Hide(); // this is the first form the user sees, I have hidden it. If I close this form then the application exits.
                lob.Show(); // this is the form that I show after the user logs in with right credentials. Textbox.text = "test" does not work on this for some reason.

            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "failed";
            }


        }

        private byte[] ClassToByteArray(Object objClass)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                XmlSerializer xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
                XmlTextWriter xmlTW = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

                xmlS.Serialize(xmlTW, objClass);
                ms = (MemoryStream)xmlTW.BaseStream;

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private Object ByteArrayToClass(byte[] buffer)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                XmlTextWriter xmlTW = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

                return xmlS.Deserialize(ms);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }



    }


}
```

Comment: are you sure textBox2 is the one you're looking at?

Comment: @Chin in the GUI Builder, the properties tab has the name "textBox2" in its "Name" field. So does the Designer.cs file. i.e this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2".

Comment: I don't know winforms, but isnt there an ID property?

Comment: I suggest putting a breakpoint on the `textBox2.Text` line, then going step-by-step. Check the value of `textBox2.Text` before the line is executed, just after, and just after `this.Refresh()`

Comment: @JonH the ID property is called "Name" and this "Indicates the name used in code to identify the object" - Visual Studio

Comment: Do you really need to do `this.Refresh()` ?

Comment: @JonH No that is not needed, but I wanted to see if I invoked the UI Thread it may show some text. I have tried 'textBox2.Refresh()' but no results. The real problem is that I'm not able to use the 'Text' method to receive values.

Comment: Id open a new project and start from scratch, something doesn't sound right.

Comment: Is the text-setting (`textBox2.Text = "Test"`) done on a separate thread?
If so, you might be getting a cross-thread exception and swallowing it somewhere. One does not simply modify controls on non-UI threads.

Comment: @christophos I am very familiar with that golden rule. Do not block the UI Thread or touch their children. The 'Text' method is called via a button click.

Comment: In that case, you might consider adding the rest of your code to the question. I don't think there's enough information given to solve your problem.

Comment: @christophos I have included more information that may help. If there's no fix from your opinion I may have to take JonH opinion and start again.

Comment: @christophos Sorry, I altered the original code, because it's simple this way for everyone to understand.

Comment: @Moynul I think you need to post the entire class that contains sendButton_Click. I don't see how anyone can help as your code is incomplete.

Comment: @Ghost Hi, sorry but I deleted that to simplify the code. Sorry for the confusion. But I think the problem lied in the Designer.Cs file. I created another Window Form file, and this one works opposed to the previous one called "lobby.cs".

Comment: @Moynul I wonder if the cause wasn't calling `InitializeComponent` twice...

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work, assuming you're starting your main form properly. You could try putting an Application.DoEvents() after setting the text property. Make sure you're not waiting on a semaphore or something.

Do you store lob as a class variable, rather than a local variable?

Comment: My main form starts how any other windows form starts. I.e default, no code is changed from boiler plate code. 

I have tried using Application.DoEvents() but still it does not update the textbox. However, I am able to change the value of the text box via code, but the text box does not update.

I am able to type in the text box, but not able to retrieve values via code. 'lob' is a local variable and not a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer for this, that I can give in terms of "fixing" the bug (If there is one).

But the solution was to create a new Windows form file and start again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug. I think you are trying to access a private object from another form.
Write a new method in lobby.cs that sets the text of textBox1 like:

```
public void SetText(string text){
 textBox2.Text = text;
}
```

Then when you are hiding the main Form:

```
lobby lob = new lobby(client, this);
this.Hide();
lob.SetText("Test");  
lob.Show();
```